# How to navigate between applet forms?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I want to create an applet with first form have multiple button, each button takes me to another form to perform a specific task.

How to do that using a Java applet?

Comment: BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to do this.  The details depend on what exact effect and feel you are after.  For example:

- A `CardLayout` in the `CENTER` controlled by a `JList` (the menu) in the `LINE_START` of a `BorderLayout`.
- A `JTabbedPane`, though that doesn't quite fit the use-case here.
- For a blocking component, look to a free floating modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.  This encourages the user to concentrate on one 'transaction' (e.g. new|edit|delete) at a time.
- Non modal dialogs for when the user can have multiple dialogs/transactions open in parallel.
- ...

### See also

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [A Visual Guide to Swing Components (Java Look and Feel)](http://algo.math.ntua.gr/%7Esymvonis/other-material/java_material/JavaTutorial/ui/features/components.html) (currently an HTTP 401 error here..).
- More on using layout managers or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>, along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.

---

1. [image]
2. [image]